# Why is my DbContext not being disposed, or why doesn't it work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

Alright, prepare to read a long post as it's quite complicated, I think.

I'm using Entity Framework in combination with Microsoft Unity and a custom implementation of a repository and unit of work.

First of all, I do have a repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : RepositoryBase<TEntity>,
                                        IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    #region Constructors

    public Repository(IDbContext context, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(context, unitOfWork)
    { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private bool _disposed;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Context.Dispose(); // Dispose the main context.
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion

    // Extra code has been removed for clarity.
}
```

I guess this is pretty straight forward, I have a repository, and the repository depends on an IDbContext (Custom interface) and does implement the IDisposable interface, defined in the base clsses, which I'm implementing here.

When I'm disposing the object, I call Dispose() on the context, which should be enough I think.

Next, I do have the UnitOfWork:

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides methods that respond to actions executed in a <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.
/// </summary>
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/> with a given <see cref="IDbContext"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="IDbContext"/> in which the entities are available.</param>
    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="IDbContext"/> in which the entities are available.
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly IDbContext _context;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Provides a way to identify if the <see cref="UnitOfWork"/> has been disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _disposed;

    #endregion

    #region IUnitOfWork Members

    // Extra code removed for clarity.

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose(); // Dispose the main context.
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

As the repository, this class takes an IDbContext also, and includes the IDispose interface, in the dispose method I do disposes the context.

Then I have another UnitOfWork, which inherit from the one above. It's in this unit of work that I define my repositories:

```
public class UnitOfWork : Repository.UnitOfWork
{
    #region Constructors

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _pageRepository = new Repository<Page>(context, this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private readonly IRepository<Page> _pageRepository;

    public IRepository<Page> PageRepository { get { return _pageRepository; } }

    private bool _disposed;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        base.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Disposes all the repositories.
                PageRepository.Dispose();

                // Disposes the main context.
                _context.Dispose(); 
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So, here I override the Dispose method from the other UnitOfWork, which disposes the context and I'm disposing the PageRepository here, after that, I call the `base.Dispose()` method which should dispose the context.

My IDbContext implementation is a DbContext (Entity Framework implementation):

```
public class OxygenDataContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    #region Constructors

    public OxygenDataContext() :
        base("Ox")
    { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IDbSet<Page> Page { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region IDbContext Members

    public IRepositoryEntityCollection<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    { return new RepositoryEntityCollection<TEntity>(this); }

    public new void SaveChanges()
    { base.SaveChanges(); }

    #endregion
}
```

So, this by default does already implement the IDisposable interface.

Now, I'm having Unity to resolve the interfaces to their concrete types:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, OxygenDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

And in the global.asax file, I disposes the object in the EndRequest (I explicitely needed this code because otherwise it seems that dispose is not being called):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var container = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnityContainer>();

    container.Resolve<IDbContext>().Dispose();
    container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>().Dispose();
}
```

But, when I open a page right now and retrieve content from the database that's working, however, when I change the data in the database directly, by using SQL Server Management Explorer, and refresh the page, the page still displays the old data however that I think that everything is disposed correctly.

Anyone has an idea, it's driving me nuts?

**Edit**

It seems like the context is being disposed, but I'm using a VirtualFileProvider and in their the returned value is not updated.

Also, when the application is started and I'm pressing CTRL-F5 (Keep pressed), then various errors will popup, one of them being:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

Is this expected behaviour in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the issue.

The problem that I have was in the VirtualFileProvider for MVC, there I was using the repositories through the unit of work without disposing them.

I've modified them so now the data is retrieved by using `Using` statement to connect to the database.
All the issues have been gone right now.

Comment: I’d probably argue that its a long, complicated post because your solution is long and complicated.. Perhaps rethink your architecture on this one?